# Watchify pipe output to eslint

Tags: javascript, browserify, watchify, eslint

Would anyone know how I can pipe output from Watchify to eslint - and have it report linting issues in the CLI while still building the outputted JS ?

[Watchify](https://github.com/substack/watchify) states that you can pipe to a command using `-o`.

```
watchify main.js -o 'uglifyjs -cm > static/bundle.min.js'
```

[Eslint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--stdin) says you can read from stdin by using the `--stdin` flag.

So with this knowledge I'm using the following command:

```
watchify main.js -o 'eslint --stdin > static/bundle.js'
```

What this actually does is output eslint warnings to `static/bundle.js`.
I'd still like it to report to the CLI yet build the JS when linting passes. Is that possible?

I'm just looking for a CLI solution using the modules directly. I'm not planning on using Gulp/Grunt or equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watchify, unfortunately, requires that you specify an output file, meaning that you'll be unable to stream/pipe the `--stdin` flag from eslint to watchify output.

In order to use the `--stdin` flag, the input must be in the form of a previous command that resulted in output to the shell's `stdout`. eslint would then take that data, and lint it, sending the output of the eslint command only, to the systems `stdout`... which is what you see when eslint responds with any problems or successes.

Since watchify is bundling your source files, it's probably a better idea to lint first, and *then* execute watchify. Alternatively, you could do both at the same time.  Here are examples of each:

**eslint first:**

```
eslint /path/to/src && watchify watchify main.js -o 'uglifyjs -cm > static/bundle.min.js'
```

**concurrently:**

```
eslint /path/to/src & watchify watchify main.js -o 'uglifyjs -cm > static/bundle.min.js'
```